# Firebase Database run in service

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How is it possible to do that in Firebase Database can also run a service in if the program is not running, there is no lobby.

I should like to watch the service on the database, and run operations on the basis of various commands without user intervention.

Comment: I believe you should try and see if it is possible or not before posting a question.

Comment: Hello.
I tried, I failed, so I asked that it be at all possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The only thing Firebase need is a Context. Service has that.

Comment: Hello
Can you help in how and where?

Comment: Hello
Can you help in how and where?

Comment: Hi, you need to setup Service first, follow this tutorial for that: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html , https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html . Notice, if you want mean for communication between Service and another Activity or Service, consider service binding.

Comment: Hello
I understand that, but I do not get an answer from them as to why the service is not running in the database. While running in the foreground or background of the app will run very much for your service as well. As soon as I step out of the app is not out of the service communicates, and continues to run in the background.